# Copy vector<Base*> when Base is an abstract class

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, polymorphism

If I have three classes - `Base`, `Derived1` and `Derived2`, and I want to create a `vector<Base*> collection`. When I try to copy the vector like this in another class' copy constructor:

```cpp
for (Base *object: other.collection) {
     this->collection.push_back(new Base(&object));
}
```

I get the error: `Allocating an object of abstract class type 'Base'`. But even though the `Base` class is abstract, I have defined the pure virtual methods in all derived classes, so there shouldn't be a problem:

```cpp
class Base {
public:
    Base();
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual std::ostream &print(std::ostream &out) const = 0;
    virtual std::istream &read(std::istream &in) = 0;
protected:
    //something
};
```

```cpp
class Derived1 : virtual public Base {
public:
    Derived1();
    virtual std::istream &read(std::istream &in); // has definition in .cpp file
    virtual std::ostream &print(std::ostream &out) const; //also has definition in .cpp file
protected:
    // something
};
```

```cpp
class Derived2 : virtual public Base {
public:
    Derived2();
    virtual std::istream &read(std::istream &in); // has definition in .cpp file
    virtual std::ostream &print(std::ostream &out) const; //also has definition in .cpp file
protected:
    // something
};
```

`Derived1` and `Derived2` are jointly inherited by a fourth class, which, like these two, has the methods `read()` and `print()` defined. Why am I getting the error, even though all derived classes have the pure virtual methods implemented?

Comment: `vector` of naked owned pointers is almost never a good idea.

Comment: I haven't studied unique_ptr yet and I am not allowed to use Boost. That's why I need it.

Comment: Moreover, I don't understand how my question was marked a duplicate, when the supposed "similar question" doesn't use an abstract base class at all. Even if I try to make the change, when I implement the `clone()` method I get the same error, so It's now a vicious circle. Please correct me, if I'm wrong.

Comment: Sounds like an error in your implementation of the `clone` method, not shown here.

Comment: Note that the duplicate's accepted answer is pretty old. `auto_ptr` is deprecated, and returning an owning pointer is widely considered an error. A `clone` member should look like `virtual std::unique_ptr<T> clone() const;` in most cases.

Comment: I've updated the dupe target list with a C++11 version of the first duplicate

Comment: @NathanPierson I just wrote `virtual Base *clone() const {
        return new Base(*this);
    }` inside the Base.hpp file and the same thing for the derived classes.

Comment: What's a `Card`? More relevantly, `clone` should only have an implementation for concrete classes. If `Card` is your abstract base class, just leave its `clone` method pure virtual.

Comment: Thank you for the updates, but I am not allowed to use these new features (the unique and auto pointers). I'll have to stick to the raw pointers for this assignment.

Comment: Yes, Card is the name of the Base class. I changed it for simplicity but forgot to change it in the comment. Now it's fixed.

Comment: @NathanPierson That did the trick, thank you. It seems to work now! Again, thank you very much!